# Convert Java Long value to value in php

Tags: java, php

This Java code converts a timestamp into a Long value:

```
Long.toString(new Timestamp(System.currentTimeMillis()).getTime(), 36)
```

As a result I'm getting `h0zgkwm7` value with encoded timestamp.

How can I decode it into timestamp with PHP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you've encoded it in base 36.

You can decode it like so...

```
$decNumber = base_convert($str, 36, 10);
```